# How to close all visible applications in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

With Mac and Windows, I was able to list all running and non-background applications and then close them with a loop. Something like this with Applescript:

```
tell application "System Events" to set openApps to the name of every process whose background only is false

tell application "System Events"
    repeat with appToQuit in openApps
        if ((appToQuit as string) is not equal to "Terminal") then
            set theID to (unix id of processes whose name is appToQuit)
            try
                do shell script "kill -9 " & theID
            end try
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Is there a way to do this with Ubuntu, preferably without having to install a new package?

Comment: `sudo halt` should do

Comment: @Marged Doesn't sudo halt stop the system also? I'd like a way of closing the open applications without stopping the system

Comment: Please clarify what is meant by "running" and "non-background" -- in Linux those terms might have different meanings than those do in Apple systems.

Comment: @agc any application that's visible to the user e.g. an open Firefox browser window. Just like with the Applescript snippet, I would like it so that all other windows close except the Terminal.